# CoreData migrations without versioning

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

Right now I use versioning to make any changes in a database. But it brings some problems. For example it's hard to merge a feature branch with a new db version into a master/dev where somebody also added a new version.

So my question:
Is it safe to change db in a single xcdatamodel without adding new versions? I tried so and it works but everywhere on the internet I see warnings that you must not do that.

iOS9+.

I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37264096/5328417 but it's without a proof

Comment: Is your app in the App Store?

Comment: Describe the **exact** changes you made.

Comment: @kirander yes, it's in the App Store

Comment: @TomHarrington adding/removing tables, adding/removing columns, renaming

Comment: See the [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/220/) from Session 220 in 2015, from about 18’15.  There’s a discussion about model caching.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @pbasdf noted, since iOS 9 you can do a lightweight migration without adding any new model version. Source model (previous model version) is cached to store and used as a last ditch effort during lightweight migration.

I am using this feature in my own apps successfully. Although I was not able to find this documented. Just that [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/220/) (18'15 Model Caching) mentioned. This is exactly the reason why Core Data is so mysterious sometimes..

Answer (score 0):

If your app is in development stage then you may use one model without versioning.

But if it is release on the App Store then you have to create the versions when you make changes (such as adding a new attribute, adding a new entity, renames attributes etc.). Otherwise, Core Data won't perform [lightweight migration](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH4-SW1).

Comment: Evenmore, it will crash when performing migration.

Comment: Are you sure that you pass during initialization Core Data Stack these options`NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true`?

Comment: What do you want to say?

Comment: Check out a comment from @pbasdf. It looks like it must work without creating a new version